# Backend module to find sections

Tags: admin, search, ce-1.9.2.0

I came across a free extension recently that created a small "locate" menu item in the admin menu bar. When clicked it would popup a small auto-complete textbox allowing you to find and navigate to admin sections quickly.

I can't remember bookmarking it, and I've tried searching for it but to no avail. Has anyone heard of this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found it** ... 2 actually!

The original one I was looking for is Alan Storm's Pulse Launcher:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pulse-storm-launcher.html

And the other one I came across was a Magento launcher from BubbleCode:
http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2013/03/25/a-powerful-launcher-for-magento-admin-panel/

Hopefully this helps sometime as well.